# Migrations are not being created since VS2017 upgrade

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using VS2017. since the last upgrade I have not been able to create migration scripts.

This is my context class:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext(
        DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options ) : base( options )
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Address");
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public Int64 AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressRef { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ServerTs { get; set; }
    public string ServerRef { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string AccountRef { get; set; }
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
}
```

I go to 'Package Manager Console'.
I set the default project to this project.
I type in 'Add-Migration InitialCreate'

It 'runs'
Then finishes without any errors. Yet, the Migrations folder is not created.

Have I missed a step out and cannot remember and upgrading to the latest version of VS2017 is just a coincidence?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/ package? Which VS version?

Comment: hi @ErikEJ. I have indeed, The version of entity is v2.0.1 and the vs017 version is: 15.4.4

Comment: What type of project is this?

Comment: Hi, it is an asp.net core 2.0 project

Comment: Cannot repro on my PC

Comment: @ErikEJ thanks for taking the time to try this out. i am suspecting i may need to reinstall VS2017.  I am just building a VM to test this out, Thanks again

Comment: You might be hitting issue [#10298](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10298#issuecomment-345393326)...

Comment: thanks will take a look as soon as I can :)